# Get value as swift type from Unmanaged<AnyObject> . For example: ABRecordRef

Tags: ios, swift, abrecordref

How do I get a value as a Swift type from an object of type `Unmanaged<AnyObject>`.  My example is using an `ABRecordRef`

I'm creating a contact object to manage once I get the `ABRecordRef`, but I'm having trouble translating from ObjC.  Here's what I have:

```
init(recordRef: ABRecordRef) {
    if let firstName = ABRecordCopyValue(recordRef, kABPersonFirstNameProperty) {
        self.firstName = firstName

    }
}
```

If it were ObjC, I would do:

```
CFTypeRef firstNameRef = ABRecordCopyValue(recordRef, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
if (firstNameRef) {
    self.firstName = (__bridge NSString *)firstNameRef;
}
```

I can't seem to find the right combination of downcasting / conversion, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Since NoOne answered before I solved it, I'll add the answer here:

```
firstName.takeRetainedValue() as? String
```

If you look at the header of the `Unmanaged` struct type, you'll find this:

```
/// Get the value of this unmanaged reference as a managed
/// reference and consume an unbalanced retain of it.
///
/// This is useful when a function returns an unmanaged reference
/// and you know that you're responsible for releasing the result.
func takeRetainedValue() -> T
```

So, because the `CFTypeRef` is converted to `Unmanaged<AnyObject>` in Swift.

`Unmanaged` uses generics to define a return type, and it is declared like so:

```
Unmanaged<T>
```

Our object is of type `Unmanaged<AnyObject>` which means that `takeRetainedValue()` will return type `T`, or in our case, type `AnyObject`.  I use optional downcasting since my property `firstName` is of type `String?`.

You can use the `takeRetainedValue` method to get your value out of your `Unmanaged` object.  In Foundation API's, I'm guessing that they will mostly be of type `Unmanaged<AnyObject>!` and a downcast will be required.  The generic formula appears to be:

```
var unmanagedObject: Unmanaged<AnyObject> = someFunctionThatReturnsAnUnmanagedObject()
var newValue: Type = unmanagedObject.takeRetainedValue as Type
```

Comment: If you are working in swift in a project that is not yet fully arc compliant, it is better to takeUnretainedValue(), otherwise you might create yourself an unintentional memory leak and zombies.

Answer (score 1):

```
import UIKit
import AddressBook

class ViewController: UIViewController {

lazy var addressBook: ABAddressBookRef = {
    var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
    return ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, &error).takeRetainedValue() as ABAddressBookRef
}()

@IBAction func GetPeople(sender: UIButton) {
    var ab: ABAddressBookRef = addressBook

    switch ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus(){
    case .Authorized:
        println("Authorized")
        readFromAddressBook(addressBook)
    case .Denied:
        println("Denied")
    case .Restricted:
        println("Restricted")
    case .NotDetermined:
        println("Not determined")
        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook,
            {[weak self] (granted: Bool, error: CFError!) in
                if granted {
                    let strongSelf = self!
                    println("Access is granted")
                    strongSelf.readFromAddressBook(strongSelf.addressBook)
                }
                else{
                    println("Access is not granted")
                }
        })
    default:
        break
    }
}

func readFromAddressBook(addressBook: ABAddressBookRef){
    let allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook).takeRetainedValue() as NSArray

    for person:ABRecordRef in allPeople{
        if let firstName = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty) {
            if let lastName = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty) {
                let ln:String = (lastName.takeRetainedValue() as? String) ?? ""
                let fn:String = (firstName.takeRetainedValue() as? String) ?? ""
                println("\(ln) - \(fn)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Answers are most useful when they contain an explanation of your solution to the question's problem. Would you consider [editing your post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28975435/edit) to add some more detail?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It is helped me!